# Restarting a Thread to restart a game

Tags: java, multithreading, multiplayer

I am making a multiplayer air hockey game as a project. When the ball falls my game stops and I want to restart the game, to count player scores. My question is how can I restart the game?

My code is:

```
package proje;

import java.awt.Color;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class BallGame extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener,
        Runnable {

    static boolean right = false;
    static boolean left = false;
    static boolean right2 = false;
    static boolean left2 = false;
    int disk2x = 60;
    int disk2y = 20;

    int disk1x = 60;
    int disk1y = 450;

    public boolean intersects(Rectangle r, Rectangle p) {
        int a;
        int b;
        int radiusR = (r.width / 2);
        int radiusP = (p.width / 2);
        double hip;
        a = Math.abs((r.x) - (p.x));// x düzleminde yarıçapları farkı
        b = Math.abs((r.y)) - ((p.y));// y düzleminde yarıçapları farkı
        hip = Math.abs(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a, 2) + Math.pow(b, 2)));
        if (hip < radiusR + radiusP) {
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }

    int ballx = 60;
    int bally = 43;

    Rectangle Ball = new Rectangle(ballx, bally, 20, 20);
    Rectangle disk1 = new Rectangle(disk1x, disk1y, 56, 56);

    Rectangle disk2 = new Rectangle(disk2x, disk2y, 56, 56);
    Thread t;

    BallGame() {

        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        BallGame game = new BallGame();
        frame.setSize(500, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(game);

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);// pencere ortada olsun diye
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 600);
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 7);
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(300, 0, 200, 7);
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(0, 566, 200, 7);
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(300, 566, 200, 7);
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 7, 600);
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(489, 0, 7, 600);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval(Ball.x, Ball.y, Ball.width, Ball.height);
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillOval(disk1.x, disk1.y, disk1.width, disk1.height);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(500, 600, 500, 600);
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillOval(disk2.x, disk2.y, disk2.width, disk2.height);

    }

    int movex = -2;
    int movey = -2;
    boolean BallFall = false;

    int count = 0;

    public void run() {

        while (BallFall == false) {

            if (intersects(disk2, Ball)) {

                movey = -movey;

            }

            repaint();
            Ball.x += movex;
            Ball.y += movey;
            if (left2 == true) {
                disk2.x -= 3;
                right2 = false;
            }
            if (right2 == true) {
                disk2.x += 3;
                left2 = false;
            }
            if (left == true) {
                disk1.x -= 3;
                right = false;
            }
            if (right == true) {
                disk1.x += 3;
                left = false;
            }
            if (disk1.x <= 4) {
                disk1.x = 4;
            } else if (disk1.x >= 445) {
                disk1.x = 445;
            }

            if (intersects(Ball, disk1)) {
                movey = -movey;

            }
            if ((200 <= Ball.x) && (Ball.x <= 300) && (Ball.y <= 0)) {
                BallFall = true;
            }

            if (Ball.x <= 0 || Ball.x + Ball.height >= 480) {
                movex = -movex;
            }
            if (Ball.y <= 0) {
                movey = -movey;
            }
            if ((Ball.y >= 560) && (Ball.x >= 300)) {
                movey = -movey;
            }
            if ((Ball.y >= 560) && (Ball.x <= 200)) {
                movey = -movey;
            }
            if ((200 <= Ball.x) && (Ball.x <= 300) && (Ball.y >= 600)) {
                BallFall = true;

            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(8);

            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            left = true;

        }
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            right = true;

        }
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            left2 = true;

        }
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            right2 = true;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            left = false;
        }
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            right = false;
        }
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            left2 = false;

        }
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            right2 = false;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Fix your formatting please. Additionally please post only the relevant parts of your code, i.e. those that are related to restarting the game (as an example the event handlers, drawing code, game logic itself etc. are most probably not relevant).

Comment: Besides the issues above, how you'd restart the game would depend on its structure. If I understand your code dump correctly you'd probably want to provide a button which when pressed creates and starts a new game thread. You can't restart threads in Java anyways just suspend and resume them.

Comment: @Thomas - you can't suspend and resume them, either - the methods are deprecated and documented as dangerous to use.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I agree that they shouldn't be used, but being deprecated doesn't mean they can't be used.

Comment: @RealSkeptic yes, you shouldn't do that. :) - In fact I'd probably not use threads in this case anyways but rather tasks and an executor. But that currently seems out of scope for the OP.

Comment: @Stultuske They shouldn't be used because *they are inherently deadlock prone* - from the documentation. Assuming you aim for a working program, you should not use the deprecated `Thread` methods. One should opt for the thread voluntarily going to sleep/wait until it is woken.

Comment: @Thomas Sorry for my formatting i am new user.You are saying create a "Start game" button to start the game and when one of the players game over(ball falls), show the "start game" button again ? If i understood correctly what should i implement in the clickbutton method?

Comment: @Thomas I created a start game button but what code is actually "starting" the game? I couldnt fill the actionperformed method for the button